Comedy, 80s 90s women swapped bodies after a car crash
American (Hollywood?)It is a comedy about two women who ended up in a car crash: one - young, beautiful blonde with a prestigious job; second woman - oldish, not very attractive housewife from suburb. The both die and in heaven they get offered to do a "body swap",- the young one ends up in the older's body and the older ends up in a handbag that the younger has to carry around. The young one (in the older's body) gives the older a new identity (she also destroys the TV with a hammer!). It's very funny!But I just can't find it on Google:( Has anyone heard of this?...or am I just mad???Thanks

Ahhh..the nearest i got is The Secret, which is obviously not a match. But realized me that their are too many body swap films.

@Elena: This could be interesting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_swap_appearances_in_media
I can't find anything really closed to your description, but it could worth a try ;-)

Possibly that's a French movie Vacances au purgatoire (1992).

Victime d'un accident de la route qui lui coûte la vie, Laura, une
  call-girl, refait surface sur terre dans la peau d'une mère de famille
  débordée, Lucie.

Victim of a road accident that cost her life, Laura, a call girl, resurfaced on earth in the skin of an
  overwhelmed mother, Lucia.


If that is the answer, you should mark it as accepted. Or at least specify which "This is the film" you mean.
